# R shiny: Cannot delete last value in SelectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js, shiny-reactivity

I have a very simple question:

Why is it in the following code not possible to remove the last entered value in `SelectizeInput`? E.g. I entered "a" "b" & "c" and I want to delete them all afterwards from the `SelectizeInput`. Why is it no possible to remove the last remaing value from `SelectizeInput`?

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  textInput(inputId = "txtinput", label = "Insert label", value = "", placeholder = ""),
  actionButton(inputId = "actbtn", label = "Add label"),
  uiOutput('selctInput')
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  #Create reactive values
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  #When Button is clicked..
  observeEvent(input$actbtn, {

    #Save value in a reactiveValues list
    rv$new.label <- input$txtinput

    #Collect all entries from text input
    rv$labels <- c(rv$labels, rv$new.label)

    #Clear textinput
    updateTextInput(session, "txtinput", value = "") 
  })

  #When selectizeInput changes...
  observeEvent(input$selctInput, {

    #Why is it not possible to completely empty selectizeInput? The last value just remains.
    rv$labels <- input$selctInput
    print(input$selctInput)
  })

  #Add selectizeInput to UI
  output$selctInput <- renderUI({

    selectizeInput(inputId = "selctInput", label= "Reorder / delete labels", 
                   choices = rv$labels, 
                   selected = rv$labels, multiple=TRUE,
                   options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `ignoreNULL = FALSE` to your `observeEvent` so that it "reacts" to the NULL value

```
#When selectizeInput changes...
  observeEvent(input$selctInput, {

    #Why is it not possible to completely empty selectizeInput? The last value just remains.
    rv$labels <- input$selctInput
    print(input$selctInput)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

**Update:**

After finding this link https://gist.github.com/pvictor/ee154cc600e82f3ed2ce0a333bc7d015 there seems to be a far simpler approach:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", "Select", c(),
                 multiple = TRUE, options = list(
                   'plugins' = list('remove_button'),
                   'create' = TRUE,
                   'persist' = FALSE)
  ),
  textOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out <- renderText({
    input$select
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Eli Berkow! Finally, this worked. When I am deleting a value there is always a flickering dropdown menu for ~0.5s - is there a way to suppress this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm going to try take a look. Could you please like my answer in the meantime. I'm trying to build my reputation.

Comment: could you take a look at my above mentioned problem about the flickering dropdown when deleting a value inside of the selectizeInput, @Eli Berkow

Comment: @elrey please see the following link. It looks like it simplifies your code: https://gist.github.com/pvictor/ee154cc600e82f3ed2ce0a333bc7d015